# Varnish permanent redirect

Tags: redirect, varnish, http-redirect, varnish-vcl

I have about 10 subdomains that I need to redirect with `Varnish`.  Looking online the simplest way seems to be

```
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?oldexample\.com$") {
     error 750 "http://www.example.com/newlocation";
   } else if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?ancientexample\.com$") {
      error 750 "http://newsite.com/ancient";
   }
}
sub vcl_error {
   if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 302;
    return(deliver);
    }
}
```

However this seems wasteful when running against 10 subdomains, especially since the redirect is permanent.  I'd rather not run every request against multiple if statement.  Is there a better `varnish` alternative for this?

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably your best bet. You could try to combine them all into one regex, but it looks like you are doing a different redirect for each one, which means you need a different conditional somewhere in any cast.

Comment: In what way do you find it wasteful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar version from varnish site: https://varnish-cache.org/tips/vcl/redirect.html

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/installation/ubuntu") {
        return (synth(301, "/releases/install_ubuntu.html"));
    }
    if (req.url ~ "^/installation/debian") {
        return (synth(302, "/releases/install_redhat.html"));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
        set resp.http.location = resp.reason;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```